# jQuery 3.3.1 file upload freeze in Safari 12.1.2 and higher

Tags: safari, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file using jQuery 3.3.1 in Safari 12.1.2 and it allows me to browse and select the file that needs to be uploaded. But when I try to upload the selected file. It does nothing. No error message is displayed, at least in the browser console. This is working fine in Safari versions below 12.1.2, Chrome and Firefox. Can some one please let me know a clue to at least start troubleshooting this issue. (I also tried to debug the code but it ended up in jQuery-3.3.1.min.js and terminates.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the change required to fix the issue. Option "forceIframeTransport" In the code snippet that refers to the fileupload function in jdeQuery-File-Upload has been set to "true" in my code. (As per the jQuery-File-Upload [doc](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options) this value is set to false by default) How ever for a unknown reason file upload fails in Safari 12.1.2 and above when this value is set to true. So simple the fix in my case is setting  "forceIframeTransport" to "false" as shown in below code snippet. (please note that it's not required to have cross cite file uploads which is affected by this option in my application)

```
 $('.assetupload').fileupload({
    **forceIframeTransport : false**,
    add : function(e, data) {
    .......
    .......
 });
```